# socket.io user joins the room but room disappear right after. (NodeJS, Socket.IO, Express on MacOSX)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

it is the first time I have to connect socket to specific rooms only so maybe I don't understand what's going on very well.
In my application, users can join a game and I want them, and only them to be able to communicate between each other, so rooms are ideal for me. But everytime I managed to make a socket join a room, moments after, the room disappears.

Here is my layout, in which I connect the socket to the server, I also display a button which I use to send a socket message to the server 'showMeRooms', which will make the server display the exisiting rooms in the console => it's for testing purpose only:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bienvenue sur Pictionnary MTL</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
            socket.on('test', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- the click sends showMeRooms to the server which will console.log the existing rooms -->
        <button onclick='socket.emit("showMeRooms");'>Show me the rooms</button>

        <!-- Include flash error here -->
        <% if(typeof flash!=='undefined'){ %><h1><%= flash %></h1><% } %>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='/room'>Rooms</a></li>
        </ul>
        <%- body %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a part of my room show view, which display a button for the user to join the room, or disjoin the room if he is already in the room:

```
<% layout('../layout') -%>
<h1>This is a room</h1>
<% if(!activeUser.isInRoom){ %>
<form method='post' action='/room/join'>
    <input type="hidden" name='room_id' value='<%= room._id %>' />
    <input type="submit" value='Join the room' onclick='socket.emit("subscribe", { room: "room_<%= room._id %>" });' />
</form>
<% } else { %>
<form method='post' action='/room/disjoin'>
    <input type="hidden" name='room_id' value='<%= room._id %>' />
    <input type="submit" value='Disjoin the room' onclick='socket.emit("unsubscribe", { room: "room_<%= room._id %>" });' />
</form>
<% } %>
```

Finally, here is my sockets controller:

```
module.exports.controller = function(app, io) {

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('subscribe', function(data) {
            socket.join(data.room);
            console.log('client: ' + socket.id + ' joined the room: ' + data.room + ', now there is/are :' + io.sockets.clients(data.room).length + ' player(s) in this room');
        });

        socket.on('unsubscribe', function(data) {
            socket.leave(data.room);
            console.log('client: ' + socket.id + ' left the room: ' + data.room + ', now there is/are :' + io.sockets.clients(data.room).length + ' player(s) in this room');
        });

        socket.on('chat', function(data) {
            socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('message', data.message);
        });

        socket.on('countClientsInRoom', function(room) {
            var cnt = io.sockets.clients(room).length;
            console.log(cnt+' clients in room: ' + room);
        });

        socket.on('showMeRooms', function() {
            //console.logs the existing rooms
            console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms);
        });
    });

}
```

So, what I do is make the user 'subscribe' (join) the room when he clicks the join button (in room show view), this action will display a message in the console, for example:

client: BOIo8p6ZeYSZyKvwKkW_ joined the room: room_52dd7b30c40336683d200f67, now there is/are :1 player(s) in this room

When it displays the message, there is one user in the room, but right after that, when I click on the button 'Show me the rooms' (at the top of the body in the layout), which emit the showMeRooms socket message, the message I get is :

{ '': 
   [ 'pABJ6nFMK1_QBs5JMo6B',
     '5qnq5uy2lm-3T7hkMo6C',
     'A3M99mfldG_Q52KDMo6D',
     'HudoJiU-UO9j-mvZMo6F' ] }

My room is not one of those, (I also tried another test by emitting a test message to users of the room but it doesn't work).

So my question is what's going on :-).

Thanks for your help

Mat

Comment: many years and a version of socket.io bumped, I got the exact same problem